# Why is my view not growing accordingly to the textView inside it (swift)?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `swift` app and there I have a `view` with embedded `textView`.

It looks like this:

[image]

My `view` is below the map, hence it has constraints:

```
- top space 0 to MapView
- trailing and leading 0
- bottom: 49 to superview (it's embedded in tab controller so with value 49 it's exactly above the tab controls)
```

The `textView` has standard constraints:

```
- leading, bottom, top 4 to view border
- trailing 8 to button
- height 30
```

when I run the app everything is fine, I see the map and I see the `textView` below it. When I start typing something in the `textView` it goes up with the keyboard (thanks to this:

```
func keyboardWillChangeFrame(notification: NSNotification) {
    let endFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    if(isKeyboardShown == true)
    {
        bottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) - endFrame.origin.y+49
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        isKeyboardShown = false
    } else {
        //scrollToBottom()
        bottomConstraint.constant = CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds) - endFrame.origin.y
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        isKeyboardShown = true
    }

}
```

, where `bottomConstraint` is an `IBOutlet` to the bottom constraint (`=0`) of the `textView`. Anyway, I added this method:

```
func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) { 
    let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame
}
```

and I expected the `textView` to change its size. It's happening, but the `textView` expands to the bottom - I mean when user starts writing more than one line the `textView` goes partially under keyboard, instead of covering more and more part of the map. What is more, while going down, the `textView` goes over the gray `view` - so the `view` itself does not expand.

How can I fix it so that the `textView` and the `view` grow up covering more and more map with every new line? I don't want it to hide partially under keyboard.

Comment: 1. If you are using constraints, you shouldn't change the frame.  Rather, you should modify the constraints (the height constraint would seem like a good option).  2. What content hugging priority have you set for the view? Try increasing it.

Comment: thanks @Paulw11. 1 - Can you clarify which exactly height constraint should I modify? The `textView`'s one? And if I modify `textView`'s one, will the `view` adjust to it? At this point I don't know yet how to calculate how much should I change the constraints based on user's input, could you help me with that? And speaking about point no. 2 - hm I think it's by default, I didn't change that at all, yet...